# Unexpected Token in dropdown component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep getting an unexpected token error for the following code where the curly brace starts:

```
class Dropdown extends Component {
  render() {

    var types = ['normal', 'fire', 'water', 'electric', 'ice', 'fighting', 'poison', 'ground', 'flying', 'psychic', 'bug', 'rock', 'ghost', 'dragon'];

    return (
      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
          <li className="dropdown">
            <a href="#" className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Organize By Type <span className="caret"></span></a>
            <ul className="dropdown-menu">
              {
                let list = types.map((type, index) => {
                  return (
                    <li key={index} onClick={this.onclick}>{type}</li>
                  )
                })
              }
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has a similar issue, this is how I got it working:

```
    var types = ['normal', 'fire', 'water', 'electric', 'ice', 'fighting', 'poison', 'ground', 'flying', 'psychic', 'bug', 'rock', 'ghost', 'dragon'];

    var list = types.map((type, index) => {
      return (
        <li key={index} onClick={this.onclick}>{type}</li>
      )
    })

    return (
      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
          <li className="dropdown">
            <a href="#" className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Organize By Type <span className="caret"></span></a>
            <ul className="dropdown-menu">
              {list}
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```